# Compare colon notation with fraction

Tags: fractions

I'm working on a job interview test and there is one answer which I just don't get.

The test states that statement below is true. To me it just seems wrong. No box is provided to check. Then how do I check it correct or wrong? Am I missing something here?

66:4 = 161/2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think they meant to type "16 1/2" as in $16 \frac{1}{2}:$

$$66:4 \implies \frac{66}{4} = \frac{60}{4} + \frac{6}{4} = 15+ \frac{3}{2} = 16 \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: Good catch! A space would have helped here.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false because 
$$ 66:4=\frac{66}{4}=\frac{33}{2}\not= \frac{161}{2} $$